# Why The Phase of Electic field of a wave is defined like this?

Tags: optics, light-emitting-diodes, infrared-radiation

$$ 
E_x = E_0 \cos(\omega t - k z + \phi_0) 
$$

$$
\phi = \omega t - k z + \phi_0
$$

Why do we need $kz$ in this equation?

Answer (score 0):

The phase is $\phi_0$, you can think of it of the number that is left in the argument of $\cos$ when you set $t = 0$ and $z = 0$

Comment: The word *phase* is also used to describe the entire argument of a trig function.   One has to tell by context if the constant at the end is meant, or the entire argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here, $\omega t - kz$ shows that the waves propagates from $z = -\infty$ to $z = +\infty$. In fact, if you follow the wave, *ie.* if $E = C^{te}$, then

$$ \omega t - kz + \phi_0 = C^{te}$$

so $$ \omega - k\frac{\textrm{d} z}{\textrm{d} t} = 0$$

so $$\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}t} = \frac{\omega}{k}$$

This shows that the wave propagates at speed $v = \omega / k$.